# How to convert multiple columns from string to integer in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has multiple year columns with data.

```
df_all = pd.read_csv('../filename.csv', header=2, skiprows= range(38,120), 
                     encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

    Code    Persons    1981    1982        1983      1984        1985 ....
    S002    Angus      5,180   46,650      5,568     265,708     344,500
```

I want to convert the data for the year columns (1981 to 2020) from 'object' to 'int64'.

I have tried

```
df_all['1981'] = df_all['1981'].apply(np.int64)

df_all['1981'] = df_all['1981'].astype('int64')
```

which led to ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5,180'

and

```
int(df_all['1981'])
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

float(int(df_all['1981'])
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

so I dont know why it does not work even for a single column?

Also, is there there a way to convert them all at once using
cols=df_all.loc[:, '1981':'2019']?

Comment: What do you understand from that first ValueError?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `replace()`:

```
df_all['1981'] = df_all['1981'].replace(',','',regex=True)
```

Now try with `astype()` method:

```
df_all['1981'] = df_all['1981'].astype('int64')
```

If you want to convert multiple columns then:

```
df[df.columns[2:]]=df[df.columns[2:]].replace(',','',regex=True).astype('int64')
```

Comment: If this answer solved you problem then pls try considering accepting this answer to indicate others that the issue is now solved...Thnx **:)**

Comment: I wonder if somebody advises if I can set it via  skiprows= ?

Comment: If you will use skip rows parameter of `read_csv()` method then you lose  your data and it isn't necessary that the error arises in particular top n rows and bottom n rows